# How to make a b-spline cubic curve with 4 points in C# Unity

Tags: c#, bezier, bspline

I need to calculate a 4-point cubic non-uniform B-Spline (p0, p1, p2, p3) that interpolates p0 and p3.

Until Now I was able to make the function calculate the curve but I don't know how to add the multiplicity at points p0 and p3 to do the interpolation. The code created until now is as follows.

```
private Vector2 CalculaB_Spline(float t, Vector2 p0, Vector2 p1, Vector2 p2, Vector2 p3)
{
    //(t)=0×B0(u−2)−1×B1(u−2)+1×B2(u−2)+2×B3(u−2)
    float tt = t * t;
    float ttt = t * t * t;
    float u = 1 - t;
    float uuu = u * u * u;
    float q3 = uuu;
    float q2 = 3f * ttt - 6f * tt + 4f;
    float q1 =-3f * ttt + 3f * tt + 3f * t + 1f;
    float q0 = ttt;
    Vector2 p = (p0 * q3 + 
    p1 * q2 +
    p2 * q1 +
    p3 * q0) ;
    p /= 6;
    return p;
}
```

I hope to be able to use this function to do a C2 continuity by joining with a grade 5 Bezier curve.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what knot vector should your B-spline have and how you obtained `q0` to `q3`.

What I would propose would be to use a cubic Bezier curve (which is a special case of a non-uniform B-spline and which should be sufficient in your situation). It interpolates `p0` and `p3`; later you can choose `p1` and `p2` according to the C2 continuity condition.

Trying to keep the changes of your function to minimum, multiplying the [Bernstein polynomials](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiVlrzYvO_lAhVPPFAKHQDHDEoQFjAAegQIABAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FBernstein_polynomial&usg=AOvVaw0d5hPuGQDNkdcW9ZAW9r4-) on a paper then lead me to the following.

```
private Vector2 evalBezier(float t, Vector2 p0, Vector2 p1, Vector2 p2, Vector2 p3)
{
    float tt = t * t;
    float ttt = t * t * t;
    float u = 1 - t;
    float uuu = u * u * u;
    float q3 = uuu;
    // q1 and q2 changed:
    float q2 = 3f * ttt - 6f * tt + 3f * t;
    float q1 =-3f * ttt + 3f * tt;
    float q0 = ttt;
    Vector2 p = (p0 * q3 + 
    p1 * q2 +
    p2 * q1 +
    p3 * q0) ;
    // No division by 6.
    return p;
}
```

However, rather than evaluating a Bezier curve in monomial basis (as you do), it is generally more stable to use [de Casteljau algorithm](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiUubSxu-_lAhWSaVAKHeZTCFkQFjAAegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FDe_Casteljau%2527s_algorithm&usg=AOvVaw3_B342EiTxWqEJ6U99Ddoa). If you want to learn more about Bezier curves and B-splines, I can recommend for instance [these lecture notes](https://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/notes.html).